# Filling any area with a curved surface?

Tags: modeling

In the image below, my goal is to fill the circular structure with a smoothly curved surface that seamlessly integrates with the existing contours. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: The problem is, if the existing contour rounds up to a flat plane on Y axis, the filling can either also be flat, or inevitably won't merge well with the existing contour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.. Maybe this is a place for a *Cast* modifier..

- Cut the object in half, Z-wise
- Grid-fill the  hole, perhaps with an <kbd>I</kbd> inset first to aid the transition of normals, and keep the mesh density nice and even
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> assign the vertices in the fill to a new vertex-group:

[image]

- Aim a *Cast* modifier at the vertex-group, 'Sphere', factor 1, with an 'Object' center, an Empty somewhere on  (0,0,Z)
- *Mirror* in Z and adjust:

[image]

Comment: Super cool technique!! Thank you!

Comment: @NewBlenderer  Ooops! I didn't mean to _steal_ your approval from Harry McKenzie 's perfectly good answer! This one was really for the archive, in case someone needed a bit more precision.. a more adjustable operation, at some expense in speed. Thanks all the same :)

Comment: Now can we do this same to Elliptical shape? What should be the topology of the ellipse before i perform this action?

Comment: I think you might have to resort to Geometry Nodes, to fill  the ellipse procedurally with a grid, without deforming the existing flange (thinner in the long axis ticker in the short axis)

Comment: Geo Nodes scares the hell out of me

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve this geometry by using [`Proportional Editing`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html).

- Delete the other half of the left over Torus you have
- Select the top [`Edge Loop`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in a face.
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to Inset Face
- Hover over the unsubdivided region and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to add [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html)
- Use mouse wheel to adjust amount of cuts and click <kbd>LMB</kbd> to confirm
- Select the center most face and set *Proportional Edit* to *Sphere*
- Press <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>7</kbd> depending which views the side
- Press <kbd>G</kbd> and align along axis (in your case press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> in my case)
- Then use your mouse wheel to adjust the size of the proportional influence
- Then apply a [`Mirror Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) and optionally a [`Subdivision Surface Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Default torus, add geonodes:

[image]

Apply. Select all vertices, add to a vertex group, select the big circular ngons (both!), inset once, remove the vertices from the vertex group, and inset a few more times, at the end you may want to get rid of ngons by <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, then get rid of doubles <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Go to Weight Paint mode, and in menu "Weights" choose "Smooth", factor: 1, iterations: 2.

[image]

Add a cloth modifier:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a clever way though!